# Find a formula a_n

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find a formula an for the nth term of the arithmetic sequence whose first term is $a1=1$ such that $a_{n+1} - a_n=17$ for $n≥1$.

I am not sure on the process for solving this. Is it simply solving for $a_n$ so it would give me the result $a_n = a_{n-1} + 17$

Comment: Are you sure it's geometric not arithmetic?

Comment: Oh, your right I did not notice.

Comment: You have $a_1=1$, $a_2 = 1+17$, $a_3=1+17+17=1+2\cdot 17$, and so on...

Comment: See if you can express $a_n$ explicitly (not in terms of any other $a_{n-1}$).

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$
a_n=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (a_{k+1}-a_k) \quad (n>1)
$$
by telescoping sum whence
$$
a_n=1+17(n-1)\quad (n>1)
$$